# iPad safari doesn't resize GWT canvas

Tags: java, ipad, gwt, mobile-safari

I'm developing a GWT canvas for iPad Safari. When I rotate the device then the canvas still the same size. I don't use any CSS3, everything has been setted in the JAVA codes(and also everything is setSize("100%","100%") ). Has anyone met with this problem? Is their any solution and why this is happening?

**UPDATE**
After a few tests it seems to be problem on every device. It doesn't resize on android devices and even on PC(after rotate the screen with 90 degrees)

Answer (score 0):

My project's sample

```
if(isIOS()) {
    // for iOS
    DOM.setElementAttribute(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), "onorientationchange", "updateOrientation();");
} else {
    // for android
    Window.addResizeHandler(this);
}

private final native void exportUpdateOrientationEvent() /*-{
    $wnd.updateOrientation = @com.xxx.Client::updateOrientation();
}-*/;

public static void updateOrientation() {
    int innerWidth = getWindowInnerWidth();
    int innerHeight = getWindowInnerHeight();
    // TODO canvas.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
}

public static native int getWindowInnerWidth()/*-{
    return $wnd.innerWidth;
}-*/;

public static native int getWindowInnerHeight()/*-{
    return $wnd.innerHeight;
}-*/;

@Override
public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
    updateOrientation();
}
```